# Launching a website via windows commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, browser, cmd

I have a program launching a website via the following command.

```
cmd "start /max http://url.com"
```

When launching a website via this method it uses the default browser with its default settings for opening a new window.  for example, Firefox and IE will open the window inside the tab of an existing window if they are set to do so.  I have reports of IE 6 replacing the content of a current opened window with the content of url.com.  I've tested this and sure enough when IE 6 is set as the default browser and with a current webpage opened the above will replace the content of the opened window with url.com rather than opening a fresh window.

Upon running some tests I see the command listed here:

```
cmd "start /max iexplore.exe http://url.com"
```

will consistently open a new window( with Internet Explorer of course) regardless of an existing window being present or not.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing a silly setting in IE 6 or if there is a way to duplicate the "always open a new window" functionality exhibited by calling iexplore.exe directly, but with calling the user default browser instead.

Comment: +1 because your initial example was what I needed. I didn't have the problem that prompted your question, so none of these answers helped - all I needed was to know that `"start http://url.com"` uses the default browser with its default settings for opening a new window.

Comment: Glad it helped. It's an old question about an issue that was ultimately ie6 related. So I hope no one runs into the actual problem anymore =)

Comment: Visit this link for more informations : <https://stackoverflow.com/a/64885208/14658432>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE has a setting, located in `Tools` / `Internet options` / `Advanced` / `Browsing`, called `Reuse windows for launching shortcuts`, which is checked by default. For IE versions that support tabbed browsing, this option is relevant only when tab browsing is turned off (in fact, IE9 Beta explicitly mentions this). However, since IE6 does not have tabbed browsing, this option does affect opening URLs through the shell (as in your example).

Answer (score 180):

### Windows

```
explorer "https://google.com"
```

Which will launch your default browser and navigate to that site.

As [@RiverHeart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739327/launching-a-website-via-windows-commandline/23039509#comment136128751_23039509) pointed out if your URL has special characters like `?` you can escape the URL like so in Windows 10+

```
explorer "`"https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+there"`"
```

### MacOS

```
open "https://google.com"
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell the default browser to be in incognito mode?

Comment: The explorer solution just opens explorer for me (Windows 11)

Comment: I don't have any Windows machines to test this, but I wonder if Win 11 and 10 using PowerShell by default might affect this 

Comment: Explorer uses certain chars as wildcards so if you give it a `?` for a query string URL it'll fail. You need to wrap the whole URL in double quotes like  ``"`"url`""`` in powershell and if you find that helpful [give this man an upvote](https://superuser.com/a/1552635/575109)

Answer (score 44):

To open a URL with the default browser, you can execute:

```
rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler https://www.google.com
```

I had issues with URL parameters with the other solutions. However, this one seemed to work correctly.

Comment: I can see how there would be issues with query params using `start explorer http://www.google.com`  as that is using windows explorer adn passing it a url.. which works.  is there also issues just using start by itselft?  `start http://google.com?q=test`  on a mac currently cant test.

Comment: Neither of those worked. `rundll32` is the only thing that worked for me. But, I was executing this from Go not from a cmd prompt.

Comment: Unlike `explorer <url>` this works for `http://username:password@localhost:8080/`.

Comment: Much nicer solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, works better than any solution I've found with the start command or explorer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 34):

`start chrome https://www.google.com/` or `start firefox https://www.google.com/`

Comment: Ideal when you want to invoke a non-default browser. You don't need to specify a path because start will find chrome or firefox.

Comment: For Internet Explorer use: `start iexplore URL`

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
explorer <YOUR URL>
```

For example:

```
explorer "https://www.google.com/"
```

This will open https://www.google.com/ in your default browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can start web pages using command line in any browser typing this command

```
cd %your chrome directory%
start /max http://google.com
```

save it as bat and run it :)

Answer (score 2):

Working from VaLo's answer:

```
cd %directory to browser%
%browser's name to main executable (firefox, chrome, opera, etc.)% https://www.google.com
```

`start https://www.google.com` doesn't seem to work (at least in my environment)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The Windows 10 BatchFile is done works just like I had hoped. First press the windows key and R. Type mmc and Enter. In File Add SnapIn>Got to a specific Website and add it to the list. Press OK in the tab, and on the left side console root menu double click your site. Once it opens Add it to favourites. That should place it in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\StartMenu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools. I made a shortcut of this to a folder on the desktop. Right click the Shortcut and view the properties. In the Shortcut tab of the Properties click advanced and check the Run as Administrator. The Start in Location is also on the Shortcuts Tab you can add that to your batch file if you need. The Batch I made is as follows

```
@echo off
title Manage SiteEnviro
color 0a
:Clock
cls
echo Date:%date% Time:%time%
pause
cls
c:\WINDOWS\System32\netstat
c:\WINDOWS\System32\netstat -an
goto Greeting

:Greeting
cls
echo Open ShellSite
pause
cls
goto Manage SiteEnviro

:Manage SiteEnviro
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\YourCustomSavedMMC.msc"
```

You need to make a shortcut when you save this as a bat file and in the properties>shortcuts>advanced enable administrator access, can also set a keybind there and change the icon if you like. I probably did not need :Clock. The netstat commands can change to setting a hosted network or anything you want including nothing. Can Canscade websites in 1 mmc console and have more than 1 favourite added into the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CLI, the easiest way (cross-platform) I've found is to use the NPM package https://github.com/sindresorhus/open-cli

`npm install --global open-cli`

Installing it globally allows running something like `open-cli https://unlyed.github.io/next-right-now/`.

You can also install it locally (e.g: in a project) and run `npx open-cli https://unlyed.github.io/next-right-now/`

Or, using a NPM script (which is how I actually use it):
`"doc:online": "open-cli https://unlyed.github.io/next-right-now/",`

Running `yarn doc:online` will open the webpage, and this works on any platform (windows, mac, linux).