# Disable message print on terminal when using Desktop.browse

Tags: java

I'm developing a command line tool and at some point it redirects the user to the default web browser. I use the following code for that

```
 if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
 }
```

The browser opens without any problem but there are some messages printed on the console while this is up. stuff like

```
 [6620:6620:0622/180058:ERROR:browser_window_gtk.cc(1082)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BrowserWindowGtk::WebContentsFocused(content::WebContents*)
```

or

```
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Is there a way to stop printing these kind of messages. (as it is a command line application it does not look good). Is there any other way to open a browser?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this is printed by the browser on startup. These GTK log messages aren't uncommon.

You can start the browser directly from the console to verify this.

**EDIT:**
As starting the browser is handed off to an operating system specific method, there's not much control over it.
To have better control you can try to launch the browser directly:

- launch the process [Launch JVM process from a Java application use Runtime.exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480433/launch-jvm-process-from-a-java-application-use-runtime-exec)
- for linux (more or less cross-distribution): [Linux: command to open URL in default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116473/linux-command-to-open-url-in-default-browser/9293402)
- for windows: [Launching a website via windows commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739327/launching-a-website-via-windows-commandline)

You can use `Desktop.browse` if the other methods fail.

Comment: the problem is these texts are printed with the text of my application.