# How can I open a site in web browser from command line?

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I want to simply be able to open a website from a curl command. I haven't been able to find anything related as of yet. All the results that pop up are mainly for mobile apps and their respective development languages. I want to be able to do:

```
curl <some flag or option> google.com
```

And then the google.com webpage pops up. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is it because you need to download the `.html` file, and then open it? Or could it directly open your URL in the default browser? E.g. this should work on ubuntu: `curl URL > file.html && xdg-open file.html` or directly `xdg-open URL`.

Comment: @Jeppe Yeah the second part. Mainly wanted to open directly in the browser, but without wanting to download the file. I will try this either way to see if it helps with my use case.

Comment: @Jeppe Yes it worked! Thank you! I did `xdg-open URL`  and it opened the site in my default web browser properly.

Comment: Okay, but then your question is not really related to `curl`. You should update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Okay just did. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets collect the various ways to open a URL the default browser:

**Ubuntu**

`sensible-browser google.com`
or
`xdg-open google.com`.

This is also answered here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/8252/how-to-launch-default-web-browser-from-the-terminal

**Windows**

`start chrome https://www.google.com/` or `start firefox https://www.google.com/`

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32775952/3717691

**MacOS**

`open "google.com"`

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039509/3717691